# Select day part of input date

Tags: jquery, html

Given an html input element with a `type="date"`, is there a way to focus the element and have it select just the day part of the date?

I tried:

```
$("#entry-date-text").focus();
var dt = $("#entry-date-text")[0];
dt.setSelectionRange(3, 5);
```

But that produces the error:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on
>   'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('date') does not support
>   selection.

The error is self-explanatory. Is there a work-around?

EDIT:

What I want: have the input focused and have the day selected so the user can type the day, leaving the month and year:

[image: Screen Shot]

I tried simulating a tab-key, but that did nothing:

```
$("#entry-date-text").focus();
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress", { keyCode: 9, which: 9 });
$("#entry-date-text").trigger(press);
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq46s98p/4/

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated. Note, work-around

Try

html

```
<!-- optional `label` for `#day` -->
<label for="day">Select Day of the Month</label>
<input id="day" tabindex="1" type="number" min="1" max="31" value="01" title="Select Day of the Month" />
<!-- added optional `readonly` attribute ; limit date input to `day` (`#day`) -->
<input id="entry-date-text" tabindex="2" type="date" readonly="true" value=""  />
```

js (updated, v2)

```
$("#day").focus()
.on("change", function(e) {
    var $elem = $(this);
    var day = $elem.val();
    $elem.val(day.length < 2 ? "0" + day : day);
    var $dt = $elem.siblings("#entry-date-text");
    $dt.val((new Date().toJSON()).slice(0, 8) + $elem.val());
}).change();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ctgog2cw/6/